# customize Ex command completion

Tags: autocompletion

`vim` provides a nice way to complete the Ex commands, which uses the `-complete=custom,Func` or `complete=customlist,Func`. It also provides many predefined completion methods such as `-complete=dir`.

Is is it possible to reuse these predefined completion methods in a user defined complete method? For example, I want to first extract the list of possible command and suffix them with a user defined string `suffix`. Example:

```
command -nargs=1 -complete=customlist,UserComplete CreateGitFile
function! UserComplete(ArgLead, CmdLine, CursorPos)
    let list = GetCompletionListFor_Dir()   " <--- what to do here
    let list1 = map(copy(list), 'v:val . "/.gitignore"')
    let list2 = map(copy(list), 'v:val . "/.gitconfig"')
    return list1 + list2
endfunction
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `getcompletion()`:

```
:echo getcompletion('*', 'dir')
                     │    │
                     │    └ looking for completion of directories
                     │
                     └ no filtering
```

Used in your code, it would give:

```
command -nargs=1 -complete=customlist,UserComplete CreateGitFile
function! UserComplete(ArgLead, CmdLine, CursorPos)
    let list = getcompletion('*', 'dir')
    let list1 = map(copy(list), 'v:val . "/.gitignore"')
    let list2 = map(copy(list), 'v:val . "/.gitconfig"')
    return list1 + list2
endfunction
```

See `:h getcompletion()`.

---

More generally, when you're looking for a built-in function, whose exact name you don't know yet, have a look at `:h function-list`.
Or, on the command-line, use wildcards surrounding a relevant keyword.
For example, in your issue, you're looking for a function which gives completion candidates, so it should probably contain  `compl`.
In this case, type this command:

```
:h *compl*()
```

But don't execute it, press `C-d` instead of `Enter` so that Vim lists all functions whose name contains `compl`.
It should give:

```
:h *compl*()
complete()        complete_add()    getcompletion()   complete_check()
```

From there, you only have 4 functions to check in the help.

Comment: Thank you very much. Especially for the way to get relevant help information for vim. I always have trouble to look up the help.

Comment: when I use `getcompletion('~/', 'file')`, the list returned contains items with `~/` expanded to `/home/username/`. The behavior differs from the behavior of completing `:!ls ~/`. Is there a way to keep the `~/` path instead of `/home/username/`?

Comment: You could use a combination of `map()` and `substitute()`. For example: `:echo map(getcompletion('~/', 'file'), {i,v -> substitute(v, '\m\C^'.$HOME.'/', '~/', '')})`

Comment: @LiuSha Please read the help at `:h help-summary`. It provides many hints on how to find specific things.